# why Apache returns 200ok for malformed app response like b'404 NOT FOUND'

Tags: openssl, http-headers, webserver, httpd.conf, apache2.4

I have a sample python app running as docker container and configured with apache2.4 and openssl (python-server.py):

```
PORT_NUMBER = 80

class myHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == "/good":
            self.wfile.write("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found\r\n\r\nThis is the good page.".encode("utf-8"))
            return
        elif self.path == "/bad":
            self.wfile.write("HTTP/1.0 b'404 Not Found'\r\n\r\nThis is the bad page.".encode("utf-8"))
            return
        self.send_response(404)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        # Send the html message
        self.wfile.write(
            "Test app to produce good and bad responses\n"
            "For successful 404 response, use /good URL\n"
            "For incorrectly formatted response, use /bad URL\n".encode("utf-8"))
        return

server = HTTPServer(('', PORT_NUMBER), myHandler)
print('Started httpserver on port ', PORT_NUMBER)
```

Results
Here are the responses i see for /good and /bad respectively:

```
curl -ik --cert '<your cert>'  https://<app-host-name>/good  --resolve <app-host-name>:443:<ip>

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Fri, 14 Apr 2023 08:06:14 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.53 (Unix) OpenSSL/3.0.7+
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

This is the good page.%
```

```
curl -ik --cert '<your cert>'  https://<app-host-name>/bad  --resolve <app-host-name>:443:<ip>

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 14 Apr 2023 08:18:02 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.53 (Unix) OpenSSL/3.0.7+
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

HTTP/1.0 b'404 Not Found'
This is the bad page.%
```

How to configure apache such that it does not return 200ok for any endpoints having malformed response body ?

Apache should return something like 404 or 500 instead of 200ok

Comment: Are you reverse proxying from Apache to the python server? Have you tried querying the python server directly to check its responses match what you expect?

Comment: What's allegedly wrong with the response body? If you misuse your libraries response API and end up with a 200 and a status line in the body, how would Apache ever know?